# Visa Type: Business & Other

Tags: uk

I selected other in my UK standard visa application for a training arranged by my employer, which is not UK based. Now I came to know that I should have checked Business instead of Other and should have selected Business Related Training . Will it impact the outcome? Will they refuse because of this mistake though I have attached my employment contract and invitation from employer stating that organization will bear all associated costs of training in the UK and have provided details of training as well. I also attached my employment contract and bank statements.